# Request authorization of Amazon Web Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, get

I am going through the [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationRequestCanonicalization)

The following code explains the construction of the Authorization Header:

```
Authorization = "AWS" + " " + AWSAccessKeyId + ":" + Signature;

Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) );

StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "\n" +
    Content-MD5 + "\n" +
    Content-Type + "\n" +
    Date + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
    CanonicalizedResource;

CanonicalizedResource = [ "/" + Bucket ] +
    <HTTP-Request-URI, from the protocol name up to the query string> +
    [ subresource, if present. For example "?acl", "?location", "?logging", or "?torrent"];

CanonicalizedAmzHeaders = <described below>
```

And, in the Authentication Examples (for Example OBJECT GET), they have show`StringToSign` like the following:

```
GET\n
\n
\n
Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 +0000\n
/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg
```

**My question:**

Why they have used three `\n` after `GET` ? Is there a reason behind that?

Also, can I write the above code as follows:

```
GET\n
\n
\n
Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 GMT\n
```

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, `\n` is not a literal backslash and the letter n, here.  It's the escape sequence for a newline character, ASCII LF, a single byte with value 0x0A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the "\n" as the separator. As the example is sending empty `Content-MD5` and `Content-Type`, you'll see three `\n` in a row.

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do but please keep in mind that the AWS SDKs can handle the request signature so you don't have to.